# popToViewController, then pushViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

After my rootViewController, there is a workflow that would go like this

```
viewController1 -> push viewController2 -> push viewController3 -> ***** viewController2
```

I would like to popToViewController3.  However, I need to go to viewController1 first because viewController1 basically determines which instance of viewController2 to push.  So I

```
// pseudo code
[popToViewController:vc1 animated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController2 animated:YES];
```

I basically pop before pushing so I don't end up getting vc2, vc3, vc2, vc3, vc2 etc.  But in doing this, since it animates the push of the last viewController, it gives the user the impression that a new viewController was pushed onto the stack, vs popping to the previous viewController.  Is there a way to get around this ? If I animate the pop and not the last push, I do not get the correct viewController I want on top by the looks of it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve (`viewControllers`), modify, and "reinstall" (`setViewControllers`) the list of view controllers managed by the navigation controller, and the "reinstall" can (in theory) be animated.  (However, I had some problems with animation in practice, though I don't recall the details.)

Answer (score 1):

can you use something like

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourViewController] 
                                     animated:YES];
```

you can fill the array with the view controllers you want on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface UINavigationController (PushThenPop)
-(void)popToViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController
    thenPushViewController:(UIViewController*)pushViewController;
@end


@implementation UINavigationController (PushThenPop)
-(void)popToViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController
    thenPushViewController:(UIViewController*)pushViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = self.viewControllers.mutableCopy;

    // Pop viewcontrollers until we reach the rootViewController
    while(viewControllers.count >= 1) {
        id last = [viewControllers lastObject];
        if (last == rootViewController) break;
        [viewControllers removeLastObject];
    }

    // Bail out the array is empty. We expect the array to contain at least 1 element, the rootViewController.
    if (!viewControllers.count) {
        return;
    }

    // Push the new view controller
    [viewControllers addObject:pushViewController];
    self.viewControllers = viewControllers.copy;
}
@end
```